# Is there any scheduled bus service at Eastern Iowa Airport (CID)?

Tags: usa, buses, iowa

Does Burlington Trailways, or any other bus operator, serve scheduled departures from Eastern Iowa Airport (CID)?

From [this tripadvisor thread from 2012](http://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g28936-i639-k5249451-Is_there_any_airport_bus_fr_Cedar_Rapids_aiport_to_Iowa_City-Iowa.html), some posts say there isn't, whereas one post states there are buses at 9:15 and 14:05.  Trailways [does have a location page](http://webstore.trailways.com/view-map.asp?p=1&l=73), but when [searching on burlingtontrailways.com](http://www.burlingtontrailways.com/index.html) I find buses from Cedar Rapids to Iowa City (9:30 and 14:05), but it does not seem to know Eastern Iowa Airport

Or is the *Cedar Rapids* bus stop in fact at the Eastern Iowa Airport?

Answer (score 6):

Burlington Trailways doesn't seem to have a scheduled stop at the Eastern Iowa Airport but when you actually look at locations of the [Burlington Trailways in Cedar Rapids](http://www.burlingtontrailways.com/locations-iowa.html?2) you will find that it's [right at the airport](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=2818+Lippisch+Place+SW,+Cedar+Rapids,+IA+52401&hl=en&sll=41.836486,-91.616588&sspn=0.797039,1.612244&hnear=Lippisch+Pl+SW,+Cedar+Rapids,+Iowa+52404&t=m&z=16&iwloc=lyrftr:m,5933826482907991358,41.891592,-91.708739).

In addition to this you can probably consult the [Airport's Ground Transportation page](http://www.eiairport.org/at-the-airport/transportation/) which also lists [Cedar Rapids Bus Route 11](http://www.cedar-rapids.org/resident-resources/transit/routes/pages/route11.aspx) as servicing the airport but I don't think you will need it.

Comment: Greyhound and Trailways buses used to stop at the Ground Transportation Center downtown, but they are now stopping at the airport.